# Cannot assign a user in Django

Tags: python, django

i have a simple chat application where i've customize the Authentication back end to use only the name. So far it is working and the users is logged in using Django login().

Now i have a problem with assign a user where this Error came up and cus the rest of the app to stop:

```
    ValueError: Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject:
    <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser 
    object at 0x7f7db7b71e80>>": "PChat.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

***View.py***

```
from chatbot import settings
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from Pchat.models import  PChat
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


@csrf_exempt 
def P_home(request):
    context= locals()
    template= 'P_home.html'
    return render(request,template,context)

@csrf_exempt 
def P_chat(request):
   context= locals()
   template= 'P_chat.html'
   return render(request,template,context)

@csrf_exempt 
def LogIIn(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
      name = request.POST.get('param1')
      user = authenticate(username=name)
      login(request, user)
  return HttpResponse("OK")

  @csrf_exempt 

  def Post(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
       msg = request.POST.get('param1')
       if request.user.is_authenticated():
          c = PChat(user=request.user, message=msg)
          c.save()
          return JsonResponse({ 'msg': msg, 'user': c.request.user })
       else:
        return HttpResponse("Account None")
```

***models.py***

```
  from django.db import models
  from django.db import models
  from django.contrib.auth.models import User

  class PChat(models.Model):
      created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      user = models.ForeignKey(User)
      message = models.CharField(max_length=200)

      def __unicode__(self):
             return self.message
```

***auth_backend.py***

```
   from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
   from django.contrib.auth.models import User

   class PasswordlessAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
        """Log in to Django without providing a password."""
      def authenticate(self, username=None):
         try:
             return User.objects.get(username=username)
         except User.DoesNotExist:
             return None

      def get_user(self, user_id):
          try:
             return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
          except User.DoesNotExist:
             return None
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, there are several errors on your code:

1) In **P_home** and **P_chat** you are using locals(), that's not recommended. You must avoid that whenever possible. You need to be explicit with data passed to the *context* dictionary.

2) In **LogIIn** view you must call login function when user is not None. [1]

3) The final error is in **Post** view, you must ask first wheter **request.user** is authenticated or not using **request.user.is_authenticated()** function. If the user is authenticated, then **request.user** is a normal **User** instance in other case its going to be an **AnonymousUser**, they both are different things. The field **user** in **PChat** model is expecting an **User** instead an **AnonymousUser** instance.

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in

Comment: i'ev tired using   request.user.is_authenticated()  faction but now i got this error:  ValueError: The view Pchat.Pviews.Post didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Comment: You need to ensure that your view is returning something. If the user is not authenticated return a JsonResponse with the corresponding error as suggested by NeErAj KuMaR.

Comment: it looks like the users is not authenticated because when i checked the DB the Pchat model/table is empty,meas that c.save didn't worked

Answer (score 1):

You have problem in line:

```
c = PChat(user=request.user, message=msg)
```

request.user is not a User object. Firstly check request.user is actual user or not.

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
  c = PChat(user=request.user, message=msg)
       c.save()   
       return JsonResponse({ 'msg': msg, 'user': c.user.username })
else:
    return JsonResponse({ 'msg': 'user is not logged in' })
```

**Edit**

```
def Post(request): 
    if request.method == "POST":
        msg = request.POST.get('param1')
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
           c = PChat(user=request.user,         message=msg) 
          c.save() 
          return JsonResponse({ 'msg': msg, 'user': c.request.user }) 
    return HttpResponse("Account None")
```

Comment: thank you for the feed back, i've tried you solution by i got this error  `
ValueError: The view Pchat.Pviews.Post didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Comment: Because you didn't have HttpResponse for GET request in Post view